# Show list of SQL Server Agent operators in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-agent

How can I see (with a query) the list of operators of SQL Server Agent with their e-mail address?

I am asking it because i want to put more than one e-mail address and I used the `msdb.dbo.sp_update_operator` construct as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12516451/1008588), but unfortunally I can use only 100 characters so I want to check if the were a truncation.

Comment: How many Email addresses you are trying to insert and length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get, through the following query, all of the operators email addresses, along with a lot of other potentially useful information.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysoperators]
```

Comment: The correct query is SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysoperators